# Can't set method setResult in RecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my app i need to start **RecyclerAdapter.class** and wait for result, but i cant write lines setResult and finish:

```
public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView title;
    ImageView icon;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_title);
        icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item);
        icon.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String selectedCountry;




        int country = getPosition();

        String ololo = Integer.toString(country);

        Log.i("WORKS" ,"Выюрана страна под номером" +ololo);
        switch (getPosition()) {
            case 0:
                selectedCountry = "ukr";
                Log.i ("1" ,"" +selectedCountry);
                Intent intent= new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("country", selectedCountry);


            break;
            case 1:
                selectedCountry = "by";
                Log.i ("1" ,"" +selectedCountry);
                break;
            case 2:
                selectedCountry = "rus";
                Log.i ("1" ,"" +selectedCountry);
                break;
            case 3:
                selectedCountry = "nrus";
                Log.i ("1" ,"" +selectedCountry);
                break;
        }



        //intent. putExtra("country")

    }
}
```

how i need to write it?Please help me and explain what i do wrong
I need to setResult from all my cases

**EDIT:**

```
public class RecyclerAdapterChooseCountry extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapterChooseCountry.MyViewHolder> {

private LayoutInflater inflater;

List<CountryInformation> data = Collections.emptyList();

public RecyclerAdapterChooseCountry(Context context, List<CountryInformation> data) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.country_list, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view, mActivity /*<- cant add this*/ );
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    CountryInformation information = data.get(position);

    holder.title.setText(information.title);
    holder.icon.setImageResource(information.iconId);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}


public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView title;
    ImageView icon;

    private Activity mActivity;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView, Activity mActivity  ) {
        super(itemView);

        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_title);
        icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item);
        icon.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.mActivity = mActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String selectedCountry;

        int country = getPosition();

        String ololo = Integer.toString(country);

        Log.i("WORKS", "Выюрана страна под номером" + ololo);
        switch (getPosition()) {
            case 0:
                selectedCountry = "ukr";
                Log.i("1", "" + selectedCountry);
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("country", selectedCountry);
                mActivity.setResult(mActivity.RESULT_OK, intent);
                mActivity.finish();

                break;
            case 1:
                selectedCountry = "by";
                Log.i("1", "" + selectedCountry);
                break;
            case 2:
                selectedCountry = "rus";
                Log.i("1", "" + selectedCountry);
                break;
            case 3:
                selectedCountry = "nrus";
                Log.i("1", "" + selectedCountry);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Can't set method setResult in RecyclerAdapter

`setResult` is not accessible inside `MyViewHolder` class becuase [setResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) is define inside Activity class

For accessing `setResult` from non Activity class pass Activity context in Adapter constructor when creating object of Adapter:

```
private Activity mActivity;
public MyViewHolder(View itemView,Activity mActivity) {
        super(itemView);
        /...your code here..
        this.mActivity=mActivity;
 }
```

use `mActivity` for accessing `setResult` inside onClick of Button

Comment: I foolowed your instructions, but i have problem , when i write line 'private Activity mActivity' and define this activity like a second parametr of MyViewfolder ,i have error in onCreateViewHolder , in line 'MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view ); Error says that i need to add second parameter  (Activity) but i cant add mActivity

Comment: @Ololoking: yes dear change `MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);` line to ``MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view,mActivity);`` and also add `Activity mActivity` in adapter constructor.

Comment: i have edit my question because i didnt understand your explain . pls answer

Comment: @Ololoking: Change `public RecyclerAdapterChooseCountry(Context context, List<CountryInformation> data) { 
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data = data;
}` to `private Activity mActivity;public RecyclerAdapterChooseCountry(Activity mActivity,Context context, List<CountryInformation> data) {this. mActivity= mActivity;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data = data;
}`

Comment: @Ololoking: and when creating object of `RecyclerAdapterChooseCountry` class then pass YourCurrentActivity.this as first paramter

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setResult()` and `finish()` by passing activity as a parameter to `RecyclerAdapter`, then access it using `activity.setResult()`, `activity.finish()`

Answer (score 1):

You can get activity from context

```
 if (context instanceof Activity)
     ((Activity) context).setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is difference between an Activity object and A Context object(if there is confusion, better read the documentation for better understanding)
So, the answer is simple,

Whe u want to do an activity based operation, follow like this

```
Activity activity = this;
Context context = ActivityName.this;
```

Pass both the objects in the adapter and then use

```
 activity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent);
 activity.finish();
```

and for context-based operations use

```
Intent i = new Intent(ListViewAdapter.this.mContext,EventPrivacyAndTicketPrice.class);
```

see full activity code below:

```
public class EventType extends AppCompatActivity {
Intent intent;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_ticket_type_and_price);
        intent = getIntent();
        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.event_type_list_view);
        ArrayList<ETypeObject> allTypes= new ArrayList<>();
        allTypes = GetData();

        ListViewAdapter listViewAdapter= new       ListViewAdapter(allTypes,EventType.this,intent,this);
        listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);

    }

    public ArrayList<ETypeObject> GetData(){
        ArrayList<ETypeObject> allTypes= new ArrayList<>();
        allTypes.add(new ETypeObject("Conference",0));
        allTypes.add(new ETypeObject("Seminar, Talk",0));
        allTypes.add(new ETypeObject("Tradeshow, Expo, Product Launch",0));

   return allTypes;
    }


}

class ETypeObject {
   public String name;
    public int imageId;

    public ETypeObject(String name, int imageId) {
        this.name = name;
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }

    public ETypeObject() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getImageId() {
        return imageId;
    }

    public void setImageId(int imageId) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }
}




 class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    Activity activity;
    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<ETypeObject> allTypes= new ArrayList<>();
    Intent intent;
    public ListViewAdapter(){}

    public ListViewAdapter(ArrayList<ETypeObject> AllTypes, Context context,Intent intent,Activity activity){
        mContext = context;
        allTypes = AllTypes;
        activity =activity;
        this.intent = intent;

    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return allTypes.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return allTypes.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i1, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater= (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (layoutInflater!=null){
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.lay1,null);

        }

        TextView type;


        type = view.findViewById(R.id.parentInteresttext);

        type.setText(allTypes.get(i1).getName());

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               // Toast.makeText(mContext,allTypes.get(i1).getName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if (intent.getBooleanExtra("fromThirdActivty",false)){

                    Intent i = new Intent();
                    i.putExtra("eventType",allTypes.get(i1).getName());
                    activity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent);
                    activity.finish();

                }


                Intent i = new Intent( ListViewAdapter.this.mContext,OtherActivity.class);

                i.putExtra("eventType",allTypes.get(i1).getName());
                ListViewAdapter.this.mContext.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For java:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();                
intent.putExtra("dataKey","DataValue");
((YOURACTIVITY)context).setResult(2,intent);
```

For Kotlin:

```
(context as YourActivity).setResult()
```